# SQL Error date is incompatible with int

Tags: mysql, excel

Can Some One help me with this please. I was trying to use this Excel condition in SQL but I am getting error.

```
EXCEL Condition = "=DATE(2017,MONTH(EOMONTH(B2,0)+1),DAY(EOMONTH(B2,0)+1))"

SQL Query = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),CONVERT(Varchar,
(MONTH(EOMONTH(hiredate,0)+1)),120),CONVERT(Varchar,
(DAY(EOMONTH(HireDate,0)+1)),120)) as 'DATE'  

ERROR: Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1

Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int
```

Thank You in Advance

Comment: This sure looks like a sql server error. Are you using sql server or mysql? They are not the same thing.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? This code is sort of all over the place.

Comment: I am using MySQL....

Comment: That's great. What is this trying to accomplish? It looks like you are trying to come up with some sort of date but the logic in lost in here.

Comment: And that error message is a sql server error message, not a mysql error message.

Comment: I was trying to get the date from HireDate . using the Excel condition Reference. like original Hire Date  is -08/02/2010
 and I would like to get the hire date as 09/01/2017 in another column as 'Date'

Comment: What datatype is hiredate? And how about a sample? And the desired result for that value?

Comment: HireDate- 11/20/1996 by using This formula in excel  "=DATE(2017,MONTH(EOMONTH(B2,0)+1),DAY(EOMONTH(B2,0)+1))" we got output as 12/01/2017.       
Now I want this in SQL

Comment: So to clarify, you have a date of 11/20/1996 and you would like this output be the first day of the next month in the current year?

Comment: And it is still unclear which DBMS you are using. You stated you are using mysql but your message is sql server. Which are you actually using? The syntax is different between these two databases.

Comment: Yes!!I would Like to get (Current Year,Next Month of Hire Month,FirstDay of Next Month)

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server management Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your Query Use DATEADD() Function OF SQL As Shown As Below,This May Work For You.

Use

```
CONVERT(Varchar,MONTH(DATEADD(dd,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),0))),120)
```

Instead Of

```
(MONTH(EOMONTH(hiredate,0)+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to get the first day of the month after `hiredate`, but I can't tell for sure.

This MySQL expression generates that, using the [handy-dandy `LAST_DAY()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day).

```
      LAST_DAY(hiredate) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If you want the first day of the month in which `hiredate` occurs, use this.

```
      LAST_DAY(hiredate) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

If you're working with SQL Server (the Microsoft product) this expression gets you the first day of the month in which `hiredate` occurs.

```
   DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(hiredate), MONTH(hiredate), 1)
```

This gets you the first day of the next month.

```
   DATEADD(MONTH, 1,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(hiredate), MONTH(hiredate), 1))
```

As you can see, it's different in SQL Server and MySQL. Job security for data base hackers.  The built-in data handling functions deal correctly with stuff like 28, 29, 30, and 31-day months, and leap years, and all those calendar minutiae, so you don't have to.